# Is there a Dart equivalent of Python's any() method?

Tags: python, list, flutter, dart, compare

I'm working with Dart and i'm looking for a way to compare to two lists, where both lists have the same length and contain the exact same items.

**In Dart**:

```
List<String> list1 = [Chris, Christina, David, Julia, Maria, Michael];
List<String> list2 = [];

list2 = List<String>.from(list1);

list2.shuffle();
```

Now, after shuffling the list2, i would like to compare the items of both lists.
My goal is to asign each person of the first list a different person of the second list (no "self-asign" allowed), therefore each person should get another partner.
If this condition is not given after the first shuffle, list2 should be shuffled again ( and again and again) until the condition ist fulfilled.

I achieved this **in Python** already:

```
list1 = [Chris, Christina, David, Julia, Maria, Michael]
list2 = list1.copy()

random.shuffle(list2)
shuffle_var = any(a == b for a, b in zip(list1, list2))

while shuffle_var == True:
    random.shuffle(list2)
    shuffle_var = any(a == b for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```

So i'm basically looking for an equivalent for python's "any()" function.
But, maybe there is an completely diffrent approach for this.

One constraint is, that it's **not allowed** to simply move the indeces of the items of list2 up by 1:

```
List<String> list1 = [Chris, Christina, David, Julia, Maria, Michael];
List<String> list2 = [Michael, Chris, Christina, David, Julia, Maria];
```

Hope you guys get my point. I'm literally super new to Dart.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: `while` already knows how to test for truth, no need to double that up with `== True`, `while shuffle_var:` would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jamesdlin have mentioned, you can use the `any` method from `Iterable`. But this is not really the full solution to your problem. So here is an example of how I think you can solve the problem in Dart, using the same concept as your Python code:

```
void main() {
  final list1 = ['Chris', 'Christina', 'David', 'Julia', 'Maria', 'Michael'];
  final list2 = [...list1]..shuffle();

  while (list2.asMap().entries.any((e) => list1[e.key] == e.value)) {
    print('Need reshuffle!');
    list2.shuffle();
  }

  print(list2); // [Maria, Chris, Michael, David, Christina, Julia]
}
```

The use of `asMap` is so I can get the `index` of each element I ends up comparing from `list1`.

Comment: Thank you! This is looking neat. Will try to figure out how to add constraints like "Maria got David, but David can't get Maria" respectively "person x can't get person y and vice versa".

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of Python's `any` function in Dart is [`Iterable.any`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/any.html).

For your particular problem, however, I would generate a [*derangement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the original `List` instead of shuffling it.  You can generate a derangement (albeit [with a non-uniform distribution](https://danluu.com/sattolo/)) with a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) that disallows swapping an element with itself.  Then you could element-wise pair the original list with the derangement and avoid pairing any element with itself.  However, you should note that with approach, you would not guarantee that an (A, B) pair would have a corresponding (B, A) pair.